# Is a bi-Level optimization problem is same as an optimization on two variables?

Tags: optimization

Is a bi-Level optimization problem is same as a constrained optimization on two variables? Does it make sense to compare these two types of problems? Given a two-variable constrained optimization problem, can we consider it a bi-Level optimization problem and vice-versa? Could anyone give me an example to differentiate these two types of optimization problems? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Who told you that? That's not correct. Just look up the definition of bi-level programming.